startViewTransition flickering issue on iframe
Im using the View Transition API.
When im click on some button, im using document.startViewTransition for general transition and its works well.
However, when im using my html page through an iframe, the transition make the whole iframe to flick before the transition starts.
Any ideas what can be the cause?
I expected the transition will work well on iframe also.
